# Getting tableview cell value nil in swift

Tags: swift, tableview

[image: In this image two sections are showing and third section will be shown after scrolling]I have tableview with 3 sections. Every section has a row. In my simulator screen only 2 sections are showing . If I will scroll the table view the third cell will be shown. There is a save button, by clicking it I am passing data to another view controller. If I will not scroll the tableview and click the save button then the cell of third section is nil.

My code is:-

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        let indexPath1 = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)
        let indexPath2 = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 2)
        let cell1 = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? PatientInformationTableViewCell
        let cell2 = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath1) as? PatientAdressTableViewCell
        let cell3 = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath2) as? OtherInfoTableViewCell

 guard let name = nameTextField.text,
            let id = cell1.patientTextField.text,
            let dob = cell1.dobTextField.text,
            let street = cell1.streetAdressTextField.text,
            let city = cell2.cityTextField.text,
            let state = cell2.stateTextField.text,
            let zip = cell2.zipTextField.text,
            let country = cell2.CountryTextField.text,
            let practioner = cell3.practionerTextField.text,
            let lcode = cell3.lcodeTextField.text,
            let qty = cell3.qtyTextField.text,
            let prescription = cell3.PrescriptionTextView.text,
            let klLevel = cell3.kLevelTextField.text,
            let deviceType = cell3.deviceTypeTextField.text,
        let guardian = cell3.guardianTextField.text,
        let relationship = cell3.relationshipwithPatient.text
        
        else {
            return
        }
        
        let patient = PatientInformationModel(name: name, id: id, dob: dob, streetAdress: street, city: city, state: state, zip: zip, country: country, klevel: klLevel, deviceType: deviceType, visitType: "visitType", deliveryLocation: "deliveryLocation", lCode: lcode, qty: qty, descripePrescription: prescription, practioner: practioner, guardian: guardian, relationship: relationship)
       
        
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(patient) {
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            defaults.set(encoded, forKey: "SavedPerson")
        }
        
        
        if let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Pdf", bundle: nil) as? UIStoryboard{
            captureSignature { (sign) in
                signatureImage = sign?.image
                print("signature image is \(signatureImage)")
                
            }
             let PatientListViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "GeneratePdfViewController") as? GeneratePdfViewController

            PatientListViewController?.signatureImage = signatureImage
                              self.navigationController?.pushViewController(PatientListViewController!, animated: true)
            }
```

in this above code, if i am clicking on save button without scrolling to bottom , i am getting cell3 value nil.Is there any soution. please help me.

Comment: This is true because cells are only created when needed in the UI.  They aren't intended as storage containers.  Save the information in a data model and use that for saving.

Comment: Hi @PhillipMills thanks for your response. still i am getting cell3 as nil.

Comment: Of course you are.  That's why you shouldn't depend on cells for getting data.

Comment: ok. then how to do this task? there are textfield also present in cell3. i want to pass all the data to another viewcontroller. please suggest any other solution.

Comment: "Save the information in a data model and use that for saving."  (And for passing to your other controller.)

Comment: yes i am saving it to data model. but once i enter the data through text field then only i can save. but i am unable to get the text field of the third cell.

Comment: Get it when it's being entered by using a delegate to see how it changes.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate